# Count after Where Exception

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following code using Entity Framework Core 2.0.3:

```
IQueryable<Book> books = _context.Books.AsQueryable();

List<String> keywords = new List<String> { "travel" };

books = books.Where(x => keywords.Any(y => x.Title.Contains(y)));

var isNull = books == null;    // isNull is false so books is not null

var booksCount = books.Count();    // Get exception
```

I checked and books is not null but when booksCount runs I get:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at lambda_method(Closure , String )
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.GetCount(Boolean onlyIfCheap)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass17_1`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

The exception is being thrown from inside your lambda method either for the `Where` or `Any` filter. Considering you set `keywords`, I'm guessing `x.Title` is `null` somewhere.

You're not seeing the error earlier because of the lazy execution of the LINQ query (the filters aren't executed until you try to enumerate over the results).

Comment: You are right. I changed it to books = books.Where(x => keywords.Any(y => x.Title != null && x.Title.Contains(y))); and it works fine. Do you think there is a better way to do this?